# PyBox2d: Change vertices of polygon during simulation

Tags: python, box2d

Currently I define a polygon in my simulation as follows

```
from Box2D.examples.framework import (Framework, main)
from Box2D import (b2CircleShape, b2EdgeShape, b2FixtureDef, b2PolygonShape)

vertices = [(-1, -1), (-1, 1),  (1, 1),  (1, -1)]

self.polygon = self.world.CreateDynamicBody(
                bullet=True,
                position=(1, 1),
                fixtures=b2FixtureDef(shape=b2PolygonShape(vertices=vertices), 
                                      density=1),
                linearVelocity=(1, 1))
```

I want to change the size of the polygon while the simulation is running. I tried the following

```
self.polygon.fixtures[0] = b2FixtureDef(shape=b2PolygonShape(vertices=new_vertices), 
                                        density=self.density)
```

which has no effect.

Do I have to delete the object to change the vertices? Or is there a way to change the vertices during the simulation?

Comment: which package is used here ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I cloned the pybox2d repository and use the `bullet.py` script in the example folder. I added the imports.